# Don't allow nested switches in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using coroutines in C using several macros to simplify writing code. As it is known, these macros encapsulate the code inside a big `switch` statement, and use `case __LINE__` to know where to return. The problem is that using a switch inside a coroutine will make it fail, because the `case __LINE__` will belong to the inner `switch`, and not the outer one.

Is it possible, by passing a parameter to GCC, to "disable" nested switch support, thus ensuring that putting a switch inside another switch will return an error or, at least, a warning?

Comment: To answer briefly: no. What can be done instead is to use some sort of static code analysis tool that will enforce given rules, and possibly embed it into the build system in a way that it interrupts the build process should a rule be violated.

Comment: You could define the macro to have `MyLabel: switch…`, and then, if an attempt is made to use it twice inside a function, the compiler will complain that `MyLabel` is multiply declared. That will prevent nested `switch` statements but also serial `switch` statements. If that is not sufficient for you, I suspect there is some similar kludge that could be done to cause an error only for a nested `switch`.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the macros you've created. An alternative way you could implement it (if you're willing to lock yourself to gcc + clang only) would be with labels and goto - gcc lets you treat labels like values (you can take their address) and then perform a goto with that address: [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values). That approach has the benefit that you can yield from basically anywhere within the function (if statements, switches, etc...).

Comment: Here's a small godbolt demonstrating it: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h195Thvqx) - and this is the code that the macros would generate: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MTM8r4jbM) - another option would be to use `setjmp` & `longjmp`, but those are a lot more expensive performance-wise.

Comment: *"I'm using coroutines in C using several macros to simplify writing code."* does it? Good luck with debugging :)

Comment: "*As it is known*" -- to whom?  Certainly not to me.  You'll get better advice if you present actual code that demonstrates the issue you're trying to resolve.

Comment: Agreed. This sounds like a design disaster to me. What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: I have to agree with others here. This really sounds like a complete nightmare designwise

Comment: If you use`#define StartSwitch extern int MyThing; switch (x) { int MyThing; (void) MyThing;` and `#define EndSwitch }`, then [GCC will complain](https://godbolt.org/z/GEY5T3EW1) if they are nested but not if they are used serially, because the nesting will attempt to declare `MyThing` with external linkage after it has been defined with no linkage. (The `(void) MyThing;` is to avoid a warning that `MyThing` is defined but not used.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible, by passing a parameter to GCC, to "disable" nested switch support, thus ensuring that putting a switch inside another switch will return an error or, at least, a warning?

No, `gcc` does not have support for this.